# CAB file extraction into different path depending on WinCE ver

Tags: xml, windows-ce, cab, handheld

I've tired many ways to create the CAB file for install to different path depending on an operation system in that Handheld device. I known a little that we can fix the condition to make a selective path in the file "setup.xml" but i've no any idea to make it works. Would you please suggest me how to done that?

Thanks in advance,
Stoper

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to do something that the CAB file extractor, `wceload.exe`, just isn't directly capable of.  If you want to install to different target locations based on some run-time criteria (like which OS version or platform you're on) your best bet is to create a [custom installer DLL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa924308.aspx) that moves the files to your intended destination after extraction and then cleans up the original target.  You could even have it adjust the registry so that an uninstall will still properly remove the app.